# Dynamic SOQL Query not accepting custom object id in where clause

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller, dynamic

I have a structure question today regarding a dynamic SOQL query that I seem to be entering the wrong custom object `id` value for in the `WHERE` clause.

I have retrieved the custom object `id` from my `SelectOption` list object on a button submission. I then want to add this in to my SOQL query to filter further my search.

- My list of `SelectOption` instances are formed of id and name values
  respectively for value and label formed by retrieving and looping
  through a custom object named `Project`.
- Project__c is a lookup field.

Dynamic SOQL Apex function:

```
public String selectedProjectId { get; set; }

public String returnDynamicSOQL(string customObjectName)
{
    string dynamicSOQL = 'SELECT Id, Name, ' + customObjectName + '_Name__c, Date_Registered__c, Status__c, Originator__c, Owner__c, ' + customObjectName + '_Type__c, Project__c FROM ' + customObjectName + '__c ';
    if (projectIsSelected)
    {
        dynamicSOQL += ('WHERE Project__c.Id = ' + selectedProjectId);
    }

    return dynamicSOQL;
}
```

I am receiving this error:

> Visualforce Error
>
> System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'a4S24000000aPDfEAM' 
>   Class.RAIDController.getRAIDObjects: line 59, column 1
>   Class.RAIDController.getRisks: line 71, column 1

So I have the `id` for the project custom object selected at least, am I wrong in thinking this is what I need to retrieve the exact project by `id`? Does the `WHERE` clause need me to specify Project__c.Id or can I just use Project__c?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of code can be open to [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) attack. Using the bind syntax avoids this in a clean way so prefer that:

```
 dynamicSOQL += ' WHERE Project__c.Id = :selectedProjectId';
```

Always better to be as specific as possible on data types (and in this case would also be defensive) so I suggest you also make this change:

```
public Id selectedProjectId { get; set; }
```

**PS**

Based on Matt's comment, the expression should really be:

```
dynamicSOQL += ' WHERE Project__c = :selectedProjectId';
```

(as `Project__c` is the ID of the Project object as it is a lookup field) or could also be:

```
dynamicSOQL += ' WHERE Project__r.Id = :selectedProjectId';
```

(as `Project__r` is a reference to the Project object that itself has an ID). The first pattern is what is normally used.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for getting back to me. Brilliant, this clears the colon error and +1 for security considerations. However I was hoping you could clear up the error I'm getting back and it is related to my initial question: "System.QueryException: Didn't understand relationship 'Project__c' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name." The Project__c field is a lookup field to a different custom object in my org.

Comment: @MattGarnett See PS.

Comment: Hi Keith, you're completely correct and I discovered this (fortunately, for my learnings sake) a few minutes ago! Thanks so much though wouldn't of got there without your help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
dynamicSOQL += (' WHERE Project__r.Id = \'' + selectedProjectId+'\'');
```

or

```
dynamicSOQL += (' WHERE Project__c = \'' + selectedProjectId+'\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following line

```
dynamicSOQL += ('WHERE Project__c.Id = ' + selectedProjectId);
```

into

```
dynamicSOQL += (' WHERE Project__c.Id = \'' + selectedProjectId+'\'');
```

or

```
 dynamicSOQL += (' WHERE Project__c.Id =: selectedProjectId');
```

Also `Project__c.Id` either should be `Projects__r` or keep it only `Project__c`

Comment: I haven't actually got a custom object indicated as Project__r, it's a lookup out to an object so is stated as Project__c I believe? Regardless I get an error when I try to access Project__r.

Comment: @MattGarnett Lookup field can have same API name as object api name. Please go to lookup field definition and verify the relationship name. Default relationship name would be `ProjectS` and in SOQL we use it as `Projects__r`